# Running a File in the Background With Parameters/Options

Tags: batch-file, parameters, vbscript, background-process

I am trying to run a file hidden which needs to include options in order to run.

Usually I run the file in batch, where I do something like this

```
@echo off

"%~dp0/file.exe" -a -b -c -d asdf
```

Now, I want to run this program hidden, so I use yet another .bat and a .vbs to do it

a.vbs:

`CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False`

run.bat:

```
@echo off
wscript.exe "%~dp0/a.vbs" "%~dp0/file.exe"
```

How do I run the program with parameters like this, or is there yet another way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can run your `run.bat` like this :

```
run.bat -a -b -c -d asdf
```

and your `run.bat` file will look like this :

```
@echo off
wscript.exe "%~dp0/a.vbs" "%~dp0/file.exe" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5
```

Comment: Thanks! I got through using another way, though. I started the file with a batch script, in which I made the parameters, and then hid it with the vbs file. The program was command line based, so somehow it carried down. 

Does the method work if I need to input something after the parameters? Like for example a port parameter: -p 80

Comment: Yes it will work, but `-p 80` is considareted like 2 arguments. You have to use one argument (%1) for `-p` and another one (%2) for the port number `80`

Comment: So I would do it like this `%2 -p 80` no spaces or such

Comment: For me this resolve not working. I have in bat file: `wscript.exe "C:\windows\system32\invis.vbs" "PRINTHTML.EXE" html=%1 header footer leftmargin=0 topmargin=0 rightmargin=0 bottommargin=0` and program printhtml not started and I haven't any errors. If I have: `wscript.exe "C:\windows\system32\invis.vbs" "notepad"` I see in task manager process 'notepad'. `Printhtml.exe` must have any parameter to run.

Comment: This does not pass any of the arguments given to the vbscript file, to the program launched therein.

Comment: Sure it do! Try:  echo %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 then you will see the arguments!